# Statistical comparison between different rasters using R?

Tags: raster, r, statistics, rusle

I need to compare, **statistically**, different rasters with a pattern raster (in this case a Revised Universal Soil Loss Equation (RUSLE) raster). I used different methods to calculate the environment vulnerability, and now, I need to calculate which method is closer to the RUSLE raster. I thought about subtracting each method raster to the RUSLE raster and then compare the means of the resulting rasters.

Anyone have any idea using R?

Answer (score 6):

> I thought about subtracting each method raster to the RUSLE raster and
>   then compare the means of the resulting rasters.

That is not a great approach as the mean can be zero, but the errors very large. Root Mean Square Error is perhaps the most common statistic used for comparisons like this.

To illustrate, I create two RasterLayer objects with random numbers, and one layer with the RUSLE data:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
set.seed(1)
r1 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r2 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
rusle <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
```

We need a function to compute RMSE

```
RMSE <- function(x, y) { sqrt(mean((x - y)^2)) }
```

Now use it:

```
RMSE(values(rusle), values(r1))
#[1] 0.3651395
RMSE(values(rusle), values(r2))
#[1] 0.3942261
```

The winner is `r1` (but not by much)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and the tutorial, it'll help me a lot!! Now, I'm gonna start study the R to make this analysis. Just one more question, this command 'r1 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))', I won't need to do that, I'll  just need to load the rasters, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I am creating example data to show how you can approach it; and to show that the code works (at least with these example data).

Comment: Again, thank you very much!! I'll work on this data in the next days and provide a feedback here!

Answer (score 2):

R package [diffeR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diffeR/) is a good way to start. If you want to compute correlation among 2 rasters use function *layerStats()* from package [raster](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html).

Comment: Thank for the answer!

I have searched on google about this R packages, and it looked really complicated to use. I don't have any notion in the software and using codes. Do you know any good tutorial that can help me?

Comment: There are tutorials for R and for spatial data with R here: http://www.rspatial.org/